# What is a gigabit?

Tags: bit

This is a silly question but I'll ask anyway:
Is a Gigabit = 1000000000 bits or is a Gigabit = 1073741824 bits?

A google search on "1 gigabit to bit" gives me 1073741824 bits, but the Wikipedia article thinks its a  billion bits. Which is right?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: This question is on topic - supremely so in fact, because the correct answer **depends on the specific application** of the term, and is a perfect case of where a programmer trying to solve a problem may need to pay careful attention to a distinction easily brushed under the rug by a sysadmin or service vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit):

> 1 gigabit = 10^9bits = 1000000000bits.
>
> The `gigabit` is closely related to the `gibibit`, a unit multiple derived from the binary prefix gibi (symbol Gi) of the same order of magnitude, which is equal to 2^30bits = 1073741824bits, or approximately 7% larger than the gigabit.

Comment: yes it's just that Google converter got me confused.
For example try to google "1 Gigabit to bit".

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the prefix : SI prefixes or Binary prefixes. You can have an explanation here :

[Wikipedia article on Octet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_%28computing%29#Unit_multiples)

Answer (score 0):

```
Gibibit = 2^30 bits (1,073,741,824 bits)
Gigabit = 10^9 bits (1,000,000,000 bits)
```

Also, for reference:

```
Terrabit = 10^12 bits (1,000,000,000,000 bits)
Megabit = 10^6 bits (1,000,000 bits)
Kilobit = 10^3 bits (1,000 bits)
8 bits = 1 byte ( Hence, why binary is 8 bit. (Since they have 8 0s, and 1s) )
```